# Passing variable to get Ajax result item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I am trying to pass a variable to access a particular piece of the results returned by an AJAX call.  I am getting every ID on the page and then trying to access that particular piece of data from the AJAX call, however I do not know how to pass a variable to the data object to get that item.  For example, if the results contained title text and if I were to hard code it I would use

```
    var Title = data.d.Title
```

what I would like to do is dynamically change the 'Title part'.  Below is what I have so far:

```
   function LoadItem() {



//Call REST API to load list item, pass the Item id to the service
var requestUri = "../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + ListType + "')/items("+GlobalFormID+")";
var requestHeaders = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
};
$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});

//set each data value from the response to a variable and then set each input field to their respective items
function onSuccess(data, request) {




for (var i = 0; i < formIDs.length; i++){
var x = formIDs[i]
 //Here I should display the value for that item from the data object
console.log(data.d.[x])

}

}

function onError(error) {
      //alert("error");
  }


}
```

I know I cannot do data.d.[variable name] obviously because it is not proper syntax but I do not know of any other way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try data.d[x] (without the dot)

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax to access properties is:

```
object.property
object["property"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 0):

Since the endpoint

```
http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)
```

returns *list item resource*, you could access the `Title` property like this:

```
function onSuccess(data) {
   console.log(data.d.Title);
}
```

**Example**

```
function loadListItem(webUrl, listTitle,itemId) {
   var endpointUrl = webUrl +  "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId + ")";
   return $.ajax({
       url: endpointUrl,
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: {
           "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
   });
}



loadListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Tasks',1)
.done(function(data){
   console.log(data.d.Title);
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for your input, I figured it out.  I just needed to do the following after my successful AJAX call.  I use the array formIDs that I defined earlier and pass that array item as the key.

function onSuccess(data, request) {

```
    for (var i = 0; i < formIDs.length; i++){
var x = formIDs[i]
$("#"+x).val(data.d[x]);
//console.log(data.d[x]);
}

 }
```